# ICDAR2015 text in video xml to cvs file conversion

Tags: python, xml, csv

```
using text for Text in Video dataset, downloaded both text localization data set and end-to-end data set.for each video here we get all text listed in one file, all clearly visible text with ID in Video___GT.txt file and Video___GT.xml file with all frames with <frame ID> , transcription, quality of text and the bounding box coordinates given . I want to convert this XML file to CSV file, where frame ID is the name of the gt_frameID.txt file with bounding box coordinates  and transcrption along with it.Here is a sample ground truth xml file.
```

```
`<Frames>
<frame ID="1">
<object Transcription="##DONT#CARE##" ID="1001" Language="Spanish" Mirrored="Unmirrored" Quality="LOW">
<Point x="422" y="56"/>
<Point x="494" y="53"/>
<Point x="495" y="71"/>
<Point x="423" y="74"/>
</object>
<object Transcription="##DONT#CARE##" ID="1002" Language="Spanish" Mirrored="Unmirrored" Quality="LOW">
<Point x="422" y="23"/>
<Point x="495" y="22"/>
<Point x="495" y="37"/>
<Point x="422" y="37"/>
</object>
<object Transcription="##DONT#CARE##" ID="1003" Language="Spanish" Mirrored="Unmirrored" Quality="LOW">
<Point x="327" y="123"/>
<Point x="345" y="123"/>
<Point x="345" y="138"/>
<Point x="328" y="138"/>
</object>
</frame>
<Frames>`
```

many more frames are there in xml file.
i tried the following code, to extract the frames with its ID as file name, but i am unable to figure out the trasction value for all are ###DONT CARE## and for all files only 3 lines of values i am able to get.

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import os as os
    
    os.chdir("E:\\myPrj20\\k_E\\ch3_train")
    tree = ET.parse('Video_2_1_2_GT.xml')
    os.mkdir('Video_2_1_2_GTtxt')   # to create gt files from frame id
    os.chdir('.\\Video_2_1_2_GTtxt\\') #moving to the above ditectory
    root = tree.getroot()
    print(root)
    print(len(root[0]))

    print('____________sub elemnt of root node_____________')
    d=root.find('frame')
    print(list(d))
    print('____________sub elemnt of frame element_____________')
    e=d.find('object')
    print(list(e))
    
    print('____________sub elemnt of object element_____________')
    object_p={}
    obj_v={}
    sub1=e.findall('*/Point')
    print(len(sub1))
    all_data=[]
    str1=""
    xy_str=""

    for id in root:
        print('_____frame id_______',id.attrib['ID'])
        fname=id.attrib['ID']    # opening a file with franeID
        file1 = open(id.attrib['ID'], "w") 
        for obj in root.find('frame'):
            obj_key=(obj.attrib.keys())
            obj_v=obj.attrib.values()
            print(obj_key)
            print(obj_v)
           str1=str(obj.attrib['Transcription'])+str(obj.attrib['Language'])+str(obj.attrib['ID'])
            print(obj.attrib['Language'],obj.attrib['ID'])
            record={}
            
            for pt in obj.findall('Point'):
                rec_key=(pt.attrib.keys())
                
                print('x=',pt.attrib['x'],'y=',pt.attrib['y'])
                
                xy_str=str(pt.attrib['x'])+","+str(pt.attrib['y']+",")
                file1.write(xy_str)
            file1.write(","+str1+"\n")
    print("current directroy is",os.getcwd())
    print('done')
```

[output from above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqZ1Z.png)

in the given ouput screen shot frame ID is 248 and one of the trasncription is "social" but in groundtruth text file no such value is there and in frame ID 248 we can see 5 bounding box coordinate value, but in text file we can see 3 only and even the coordinate values diffrent. how to solve it. need help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.